# Is console unnecessary Error Message slowing the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handsontable

I am using Handsontable to show some table in my webpage and it is working fine, but over the time as the client left the page hanging the page will accumulate error such as

(I can't upload pic but the message is something like this)

```
387 handsontable.full.min.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
    at t.overlayContainsElement (handsontable.full.min.js:34)
    at n.value (handsontable.full.min.js:34)
    at n.value (handsontable.full.min.js:40)
    at n.value (handsontable.full.min.js:40)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (handsontable.full.min.js:40)
    at HTMLDivElement.i (handsontable.full.min.js:34)
```

does it contribute to the page getting slower than initial?

here is the portion of the handsontable in my code

```
function table(data){
try {
    document.getElementById('data_view').innerHTML = null;
    const container = document.getElementById('data_view');
    hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
    data: data,
    //rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: 
 ['Area','WorkStation','Stepname','Commit','TechNode','Moves','WIP','Running','Hold','MTAS','Delta to Commit','Remarks','Delta to Commit'],
    //editor: false,
    columns: function(column) {
    var columnMeta = {};
    if (column === 0) {
      columnMeta.data = 'AreaName';
    } else if (column === 1) {
      columnMeta.data = 'workstation';
    } else if (column === 2) {
      columnMeta.data = 'Stepname';
    } else if (column === 3) {
      columnMeta.data = 'Commit';
    } else if (column === 4) {
      columnMeta.data = 'TechNode';
    } else if (column === 5) {
      columnMeta.data = 'Moves';
    } else if (column === 6) {
      columnMeta.data = 'Wip';
    } else if (column === 7) {
      columnMeta.data = 'Running';
    } else if (column === 8) {
      columnMeta.data = 'Hold';
    } else if (column === 9) {
      columnMeta.data = 'MTAS';     
    } else if (column === 10) {
      columnMeta.data = 'Delta to Commit';
    } else if (column === 11) {
      columnMeta.data = 'Remark';
      columnMeta.readOnly = false;
    }
    return columnMeta;
    },
    readOnly: false,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    contextMenu: true,
    afterSelection: function(r,c){
    selection = this.getDataAtRow(r);
    //localStorage.setItem("selection", selection);
    //sessionStorage.setItem("selection2", selection);
    //onsole.log(data)
    },
    contextMenu: {
    items: {
        'row_above': {},
        'row_below': {},
        'col_left': {},
        'col_right': {},
        'remove_row': {},
        'remove_col': {},
        'undo': {},
        'redo': {},
        'make_read_only': {},
        'alignment': {},
        'copy': {},
        'export': {
            name: 'Export to CSV',
            callback: function(key, options) {
            hot.getPlugin('exportFile').downloadFile('csv', {
            columnHeaders: true,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            filename: 'Commit_Download_' + JSON.stringify(sqlrefresh[0].last_refresh)
            })}
        },
        'lot_id_list': {
          name: 'Check Lot',
          callback: function() {
window.open("http://mfgrpa2:4000/lot_list?"+"Step="+selection[2].toString()+"Technode="+selection[4].toString(), "lot_list", "width=1500");
          }
        }
    }},
    dropdownMenu: true,
    filters: true,
    manualColumnResize: true,
    manualRowResize: true,
    columnSorting: true,
    formulas: true,
    minRows: 2,
    minCols: 12,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    //maxCols: 3,
    //colWidths: '100',
    //height: 320,
    //afterGetColHeader: addInput,
    cells: function (row, col) {
    var cellProperties = {};
    const cellValue = this.instance.getDataAtCell(row, col);
    if (col === 10){
        if ( cellValue > 0 ) {
          cellProperties.renderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
              Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
              td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
              td.style.color = 'black';
              td.style.background = '#4FF635';
          }
        }
        else if ( cellValue < 0 ) {
          cellProperties.renderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
              Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
              td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
              td.style.color = 'black';
              td.style.background = '#C84321';
          }
        }
        else {
        }
    }
    return cellProperties;
    }
    });
    }
    catch(e){
    }}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `querySelector` does not seem to used anywhere in the code provided.

Comment: There are no "unnecessary error messages", they all are indicating errors have occurred during the JS execution. Error messages are also not slowing a webpage. The error message in your code comes from the handsontable library, a probable reason is that you haven't passed all the information the library needs to some of its functions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this isn't a problem for the site's performance, just it's not beautiful or professional. You should try to fix the error or find another solution.